# I would like to plot points belonging to same class together

Tags: python, grouping, visualization

I have the output of a machine learning step as follows

```
(1, Some Text)
(1, Some Text)
(2, Different Text)
(2, slightly different Text)
(3, Very different Text)
```

The first value depicts the class label the text was assigned, the second value depicts the actual text.
How would i plot these values such that all the points belonging to class label appears together, i.e all points belonging to class label 1 appear together etc.

The idea is to have the user hover over the points to see the clusters of similar text.
How can i achieve this using data visualization? i.e Generate x, y coordinates that are close for points belonging to same class and x,y coordinates that are distant from each other for points belonging to different classes.

Comment: Hey Delta Five, first you should always show some code, your first attempt etc... but try looking into matplotlib to start.

Comment: I am familiar with data visualization and have looked into matplotlib and plotly. I am unable to get the intuition behind grouping similar points based on class value alone. I thought of using scatter plot but that will only group points based on x,y coordinates, these points don't neccessarily belong to the same class though.